# How can I get implicit conversions to work inside collections?

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit

Say I have an implicit conversion:

```
implicit def aToB(a: A):B={
...
}
```

How can I get this implicit conversion to work on the elements of a List?

If I have:

```
val listOfA: List[A] ...
```

and I have a function that takes a List of B, is it possible to let Scala implicitly convert all of the elements from A's to B's?

Without implicit conversions, the conversion might look like:

```
lisftOfA.map(a => new B(a.someValue, a.anotherValue))
```

But I would love for this to happen like 'magic'... is that too much to ask.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here are a few alternatives you might wish to consider:

**1. Use a view bound**

If it's possible to change the function that takes a List of Bs, this would be the simplest solution. Modify it to accept a List of things that can be converted to Bs. That is,

```
def yourFn(l: List[B]) = ...
```

would become

```
def yourFn[X <% B](l: List[X]) = ...
```

Then, you can just call the function with listOfA:

```
yourFn(listOfA)
```

**2. Introduce a conversion method**

This is similar to Rogach's first solution, except that the outer conversion is non-implicit:

```
def convert[B, A <% B](l: List[A]): List[B] = l map { a => a: B }
```

Then at your function's call-site, you would write

```
yourFn(convert(listOfA))
```

Like Rogach's second solution, this is bit safer than bringing in an implicit conversion.

**3. Introduce an implicit conversion**

This is equivalent to Rogach's first solution, but the notation is a bit nicer (IMO).

```
implicit def convert[B, A <% B](l: List[A]): List[B] = l map { a => a: B }
```

If this conversion is in scope at your call-site, you can just call your function with the listOfA:

```
yourFn(listOfA)
```

**Parting Thoughts**

It's interesting to consider how to solve this problem in a general way. What if I want to define my conversion method so that it can handle any type that implements the `map` method? i.e.,

```
def convert[B, A <% B, C[_]](c: C[A]): C[B] = c map { a => a: B }
```

This won't work, of course, since nothing in the signature expresses the constraint that `C` must implement `map`. As far as I know, expressing this constraint is fairly involved and cannot be done in a way that provides out-of-the-box support for any type that implements `map`. See [Type-safe Scala sequence comprehensions](http://tonymorris.github.io/blog/posts/type-safe-scala-sequence-comprehensions/).

Comment: Thanks for the great examples and explanations. For one, I was wondering how to 'type cast' in the map, ie. a => a: B. Is there a name for doing that?

Comment: It's called *type ascription*. You're *ascribing* type `B` to an object of type `A`. This is in contrast to a *cast*, which uses the `asInstanceOf` method in Scala, in that it is checked at compile-time and can never result in a runtime exception.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be quite what @JacobusR was asking. We would like conversion to work 'inside' the `map` function which is a function of `listOfA`. You have introduced `yourFn` not mentioned by OP, but we need `listOfA.map((b: B) => ...)` to run as if it was `convert(listOfA).map((b: B) => ...)`. It seems your solution would only work if we defined `def yourFn[T](listOfB: List[B), fn: B => T): List[T] = listOfB.map(fn)`. i.e. if we wrapped `map` just to help with type inference, which is not what we want to do.

Comment: @silasdavis It sounds like you have a different question than the OP. @JacobusR had a `List[A]` and a function that takes a `List[B]` that he wanted to apply to his `List[A]` -- I named this function `yourFn`, but it was the OP who introduced it in his question.

Comment: Has this been successfully tested? In [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200682/chain-implicit-conversion-of-collection) I show that 3. (implicit conversions) don't actually work. Please have a look if possible :)

Comment: Sadly, none of these are acceptable solutions anymore. View bounds (<%) are used in all of them, and they became deprecated since scala 2.10 a few years ago. Avoid using view bounds and use implicit parameters instead.

Answer (score 3):

The following is a general solution, enabling implicit conversion of lists (List[A] => List[B]) if implicit conversion A=>B is available in scope:

```
scala> class A
defined class A

scala> class B
defined class B

scala> implicit def a2b(a:A) = new B
a2b: (a: A)B

scala> implicit def mapI[A,B](l: List[A])(implicit conv: A => B): List[B] = l.map(conv)
mapI: [A, B](l: List[A])(implicit conv: (A) => B)List[B]

scala> List(new A): List[B]
res0: List[B] = List(B@efa0bf4)
```

Is this what you need?

Also, since you already have that implicit conversion, you can just write:

```
listOfA.map(a2b) // List[B]
```

It would be a bit more verbose, but gives you a bit more explicit control of your code.

Comment: This does not really work:

  val list = List(new A)
  val listB: List[B] = list //this does not compile.



check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200682/chain-implicit-conversion-of-collection)

Answer (score 2):

I think the best that is possible is

```
implicit def asToBs(as: List[A]): List[B] = as map aToB
```

Comment: Are you sure, there will be no problems with type erasure?

Comment: @om-nom-nom - Why should there be any? Implicits are resolved before type erasure.

Comment: +1 I did not follow this approach, but it's a refreshingly simple answer, thanks.

Comment: It does not work. Apparently list covariance confuses the compiler. Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200682/chain-implicit-conversion-of-collection) please

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, you may wish to consider a more generic approach employing [`CanBuildFrom`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/architecture-of-scala-collections.html).

This program:

```
import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
import scala.language.{higherKinds, implicitConversions}

implicit def implyConvertedTraversable[A, B, C[X] <: Traversable[X]](as: C[A])(implicit conversion: A => B, cbf: CanBuildFrom[C[A], B, C[B]]): C[B] = {
  val builder = cbf(as)
  builder.sizeHint(as)
  builder ++= as.map(conversion)
  builder.result()
}

implicit def implyString(a: Int): String = a.toString

val intList = List(1, 2, 3)
val intStream = Stream(1, 2, 3)

val stringList: List[String] = intList
val stringStream: Stream[String] = intStream
```

Yields:

```
intList: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
intStream: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)

stringList: List[String] = List(1, 2, 3)
stringStream: Stream[String] = Stream(1, ?)
```